# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS не переходит в ждущий режим

Tags: ubuntu

После обновления до Ubuntu 16.04 LTS мой ноутбук перестал переходит в ждущий режим. Просто гаснет экран, но ноутбук продолжает работать, на какие либо действия со стороны пользователя перестает отвечать. Из такого состояния его никак не вывести, только с помощью перезагрузки 
через кнопку питания.

Ноутбук hp pavilion dv6 6169er. В Ubuntu 15.10 все работало нормально.

После установки сделал очистку системы от неиспользуемых пакетов и удалил старые ядра. Возможно после этих действий, я случайно удалил библиотеку, отвечающую за корректный переход в "ждущий режим", Но это только предположение, все делалось через стандартный менеджер пакетов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, это нормальная практика пока. У меня аналогичная ситуация. Вот, что пишут в сети по этому поводу: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Ещё можешь попробовать поставить новое ядро, вот, что нарыл я по этому поводу: http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.ru/2016/04/ubuntu-1604-wont-wake-up-from-suspend.html
Мне, кстати, это помого. =)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. В моем случае драйвера опенсоурсные. Но вот обновление ядра до 4.5.3 помогло.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.